# Minimum MSE linear combination of random variables

Tags: regression, random-variable, estimators, mse

Consider the following objective function:

$$ \mathbb{E}((Y-X\beta)^2)\rightarrow \min_\beta $$

where $Y$ and $X$ are (generally *not* independent) random variables and $\beta$ is a constant. That is, I am looking for a constant $\beta$ that would yield the smallest discrepancy in terms of mean squared error between a random variable $Y$ and a scaled random variable $X\beta$. (I could have put $\beta$ in front of $X$ but that does not change anything.)

In search of an optimal $\beta$, I take the derivative of the objective function with respect to $\beta$ and equate it to zero:

$$ -2\mathbb{E}(XY)+2\beta\mathbb{E}(X^2)=0. $$

Then

$$ \beta^*=\frac{\mathbb{E}(XY)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} $$

where I have put an asterisk at $\beta$ to denote an "optimal" value.

---

This is all fine as long as I only care about these random variables in theory. However, at this stage I would like to get an **operational (feasible)** counterpart of $\beta^*$ based on a data sample. That is, I need an estimator $\hat\beta^*=\hat\beta([y:x])$ such that

$$ \hat\beta^*=\arg\min_\hat\beta \mathbb{E}((Y-X\hat\beta)^2) $$

where $[y:x]$ is a data sample (an $n \times 2$ matrix).

---

**Q1:** Is there any good solution to this problem?

I intentionally did not make more assumptions (did not specify the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ nor their marginal distributions, did not restrict $\hat\beta$ to be linear), but I might accept some if the general setting is too general to work with. For example, you may take on an extra assumption that $\hat\beta$ is linear in $y$ if that makes the problem easier.

**Q2:** What about the case of $\mathbb{E}((Y-\alpha-X\beta)^2)\rightarrow \min_{\alpha,\beta}$ that includes a constant $\alpha$ extra to the above setting?

Comment: You need to estimate the risk somehow to make it operational. Are you familiar with Stein's work? E.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_unbiased_risk_estimate

Comment: @hejseb, thanks for helping me once again! The link you sent looks interesting, but could you be more specific on how and where it should come in handy?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a complete answer (which is why I usually just lurk in the comments), but Stein's unbiased risk estimate is a common way of finding estimates of the risk. Interestingly, the related James-Stein estimator (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James–Stein_estimator) has smaller MSE than the usual sample mean estimator. I believe this could put you on the right track, but perhaps someone else will come along with a full fledged answer soon.

Comment: @hejseb, OK, thanks even for the comments. I was expecting to encounter James-Stein estimator and shrinkage at some point on the way, but I just don't have a good grasp on the details involved.